# Some questions about Trello

Tags: trello, project-management

I have a few questions about Trello. It looks really amazing and the keyboard controls are AWESOME. So far so good, switching from Basecamp for monetary reason.

So here are the questions I've got so far:

1. It is currently free, but if I look at the rest of FogCreek's portfolio every apps they made are subscription based. Will Trello stay free?! If not then is there any price given yet?
2. I'm running some projects as a freelancer so I'd like, on some of my boards, that the cards would be automatically assigned to me. Is it possible to do so?
3. Is there any batch actions? (batch close, batch assign to, etc) ? It would be very useful, I can't find it yet.
4. This question has been removed.

For #2:
*This doesn't totally answer my question but is a good beginning:
Assign Self
Pressing 'space' will assign (or unassign) yourself to a card.*

Comment: For 2 & 3, you could always use the API: https://trello.com/docs

Comment: Sure I could, but how am I going to implement the feature in the app afterward? haha, but yes I could make myself a "companion" app for this hehe thanks for the idea!

Comment: I've logged your vote for #2 and #3 on our internal feature ideas Trello board. Anyone who wants to vote for these should email feature-ideas@trello.com to express your support. Why are we using email to deal with Trello feature ideas, not Trello or something else? See "Ideas" under https://trello.com/card/what-can-you-expect-from-this-board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/1211

Comment: @RichArmstrong Nice thanks for the feedback, I'll sure send some suggestions and go vote on some, keep up the amazing work!

Comment: If you are the only one using the board is it necessary to assign cards at all?

Answer (score 5):

Regarding question **no. 1**, as per [Trello's page on Privacy, Security and Data](https://trello.com/privacy):

> **Free... for how long?**
>
> Trello is free forever. We may add pay-only features in the future, but everything that's free today will be free tomorrow and forever.

Regarding question **no. 4**, it's subjective and thus not fit with the StackExchange policy on questions type. See the related [FAQ](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As for question #4, I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Question no. 2 can now be solved with the copy card functionality.

When you create a new card just copy an existing card that you are assigned and only select the 'Members' check box.

You can then create the rest of the card details from the copy.

You could also use the keyboard shortcuts for assigning people to a card.

When typing in the card title, at the end type '@' and start typing the username. Matching users will appear in a drop down list and allow you add them to the card. Not exactly auto assign but it helps speed up the process.